# JQuery Mobile Redirect Help

Tags: jquery, redirect, mobile

This site is not redirecting to the .mobi site. Is that because the redirect script is not at the top of the "head" and is conflicting with the other scripts that are being called first? Any suggestions? Other people seem to say it just needs to be in the head area. That is not working though.

The hosting company entered the code, but put it at the bottom. Do you think that this is why it's not redirecting? I asked them to put it there and I guess they forgot. Before I ask them to do it again, I wanted some input on whether this could be causing the problem?

```
<head>
<!-- SW3 -->

<title>Rosenhouse Group, PC, a professional tax and accounting firm in Dallas, Texas</title>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
adroll_adv_id = "7LYERGMOVZEPTB3B62NLZD";
adroll_pix_id = "KN5CT4JO5NEKLEGKBSHDQF";
(function () {
var oldonload = window.onload;
window.onload = function(){
   __adroll_loaded=true;
   var scr = document.createElement("script");
   var host = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://c.adroll.com" : "http://c.adroll.com");
   scr.setAttribute('async', 'true');
   scr.type = "text/javascript";
   scr.src = host + "/j/roundtrip.js";
   document.documentElement.firstChild.appendChild(scr);
   if(oldonload){oldonload()}};
}());
</script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="favicon.ico"/>
<script src="js/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.noConflict();
</script>
<meta name="keywords" content="Rosenhouse Group, PC, L. Minton Rosenhouse, CPA, Dallas, Texas, 75252-5897, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , ">

<meta name="author" content="Emochila Website Design for CPAs Lawyers and Dentists">

<meta name="description" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sb/cssfile.jsp?decider=mrosenhouse&amp;content=1500" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[

var mobile =

(/iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.user

Agent.toLowerCase()));

if (mobile) {

document.location = "http://www.cpadallas.mobi";

}

// ]]></script>



<meta name="google-site-verification" content="Fl04TuB3stq95hUqds8jcKHuWRjxeCjO8orCnSn1SyY" />
</head>
```

Comment: where is the jquery need on this.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the source code of http://www.cpadallas.com your main issue is that the regex is across multiple lines.

Can you change it to be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var mobile = (/iphone|ipod|android|blackberry|mini|windows\sce|palm/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));

if (mobile) {
     document.location = "http://www.cpadallas.mobi";
}

</script>
```

I would encourage you to look at a more robust redirection strategy in the future.

Comment: Hey Barry do you mean just deleting that space or did you mean that and something else?

Comment: I just meant deleting the extra linebreak that is there between user and Agent

Comment: For anyone searching for a Javascript mobile redirect script.  This is it.  Thank you barry.